# What's the jumper "enable 1.5GB PHY" on a Western Digital hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, jumper

I've got a new hard disk. On the label there is a description of the jumper settings:

[image: PHY jumper]

One of them is:

> Jumpered pins 5 and 6 enables 1.5GB PHY

What does PHY stand for?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's SATA II disk, right?

And if you put jumper on these pins HDDs will be SATA I.

It's there for if your motherboard doesn't support SATA II.

Comment: Yep, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_3_Gbit.2Fs_.28Second_Generation.29

Comment: Yes, it's a SATA II disk.

Answer (score 16):

PHY stands for "physical layer".  By jumpering pins 5 & 6 will cause the drive to go into a legacy 1.5 Gbit/s mode, rather than its default 3.0 Gbit/s mode.  Check out the [Wikipedia article on SATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Throughput) for a bit more info.

Answer (score 5):

By jumping the two pins, 5 and 6, you limit the transfer rate to 1.5 GB/s.

PHY is simply the physical layer in question, between the drive and cables/transfer.

Take a look at Wikipedia's page on [SATA throughput](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Throughput).

Answer (score 3):

I bought the same disk 2 days ago.  What everyone else says is right, jumpering those pins will limit the transfer rates to 1.5Gb/s rather that the 3Gb/s it is capable of.

Also,
Pins 1 & 2 enable Spread Spectrum Clocking which reduces the drives electronic noise, at the cost of some performance.
Pins 3 & 4 enable Power-Up In Standby (low power mode).  Your motherboard needs to support this.  I couldn't find any way in Vista to get my external drive out of standby.